# Not able to write the available performance counters in the text file using ShellExecute in delphi

Tags: delphi, performancecounter, shellexecute

My Delphi application is required to show list of available performance counters in the Memo. To do this I am using ShellExecute() to get all the performance counters and write into the text file. I wanted to load this file into memo.

But Shellexecute() is not creating any file.

I have tried with following code

```
ShellExecute(handle,nil,'cmd.exe','typeperf -q >D:\PERFORMANCE999.TXT',NIL, SW_HIDE);
```

If I try the same command in the command prompt (Run > cmd.exe) then file is being created successfully:

```
typeperf -q >D:\PERFFORMANCE999.exe
```

Comment: You need to include the `/c` switch as the first command line parameter: `'/c typeperf -q > D:\PERFORMANCE999.TXT'`. But why spawn a separate process at all instead of simply enumerating the available couners yourself using the PERFORMANCE counter APIs directly? No text file needed.

Comment: Indeed. There is an API for this which you should use directly.

Comment: Could you please share the link for API ?

Comment: http://www.ez-delphi.com/sources/PDH.htm, [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/creating-a-query)